# How can i add print report option in python tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

How can i add print report option in python GUI[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bO4x3.png) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are saving your data in some text file then you can try using os.startfile('filename.txt','print') .this should do your job.